# After deleting custom validator Django crashes and can't revert back to running backup. Bug?

Tags: django, validation, attributeerror

This is a strange issue and I kind of feel like it may be bug related.

in models.py i have created a custom validator

```
def validate_accecpt_terms(value):
    if value != True:
        raise ValidationError(u'Sorry but you must accecpt the terms to continue')

class Sheet(SheetBase):
    authorized  = models.BooleanField(default=False,validators=[
                  validate_accecpt_terms,
                  ])
```

Which works as expected. But what is strange is I can remove the validator from the BooleanField and the validator no longer runs (as expected), but when I delete the method validate_accecpt_terms() and then do anything with manage.py I get an error like:

```
(django-proj)user@ubuntu:~/django-proj/bin/first_project$ python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.3:8001Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f8bf6fba8c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/django-initial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 222, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/django-initial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/user/django-initial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 159, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/user/django-initial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/user/django-initial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/user/django-initial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 173, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "/home/user/django-initial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 103, in load_disk
    migration_module = import_module("%s.%s" % (module_name, migration_name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/user/django-initial/bin/first_project/process_forms/migrations/0025_auto_20141129_0848.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
  File "/home/user/django-initial/bin/first_project/process_forms/migrations/0025_auto_20141129_0848.py", line 19, in Migration
    field=models.BooleanField(default=False, validators=[process_forms.models.validate_accecpt_terms]),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'validate_accecpt_terms'
 in Migration
    field=models.BooleanField(default=False, validators=[process_forms.models.validate_accecpt_terms]),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'validate_accecpt_terms'
```

**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'validate_accecpt_terms'**

so in order to use my app now without Django crashing is I have to add the method back in to models.py with a simple pass statement just to satisfy things:

```
def validate_accecpt_terms(value):
    """
        After creating this method and assigning it as a validator,
        If this method is ever deleted Django will crash.
        So a blank method must now reside in its place. Why?
    """
    pass 
class Sheet(SheetBase):
    authorized  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I have tried restarting the server, a database reset, syncdb, migrations..
Any insight as to what Django's thinking and a way to clear this dependency would be very helpful!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the one thing I didn't try was delete the migrations data, which did the trick.